# How to show 'Angualar Schematic...' entry in project popup menu?

Tags: angular, intellij-idea, nrwl-nx, angular-schematics

I have an angular project where the Angular menu items are missing.

In the settings it seems to be configured correctly:
[image]

But in the pop-up menu (from the project-view) the entries are missing:

[image]

Note: Some **other projects work** fine in the same IDE:
[image]

Is there maybe another setting that I am missing - or another way to make this work?

Notes:

- I have tries all IntelliJ repair options
- I copied the whole project, deleted all IntelliJ related files/dirs (`*.iml`, `.idea`, `.run`) and created a new project: still does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found out the this was caused by some [nrwl/nx](https://nx.dev/) migration.
That migration converted the `angular.json` file to multiple `project.json` files: see [nx-docs Configuration: project.json and nx.json](https://nx.dev/configuration/projectjson)

And now IntelliJ does not understand that this is an angular project anymore.

Comment: Did you find a workaround for this? I am having the same issue and I dont want to have an empty angular.json just so intellij works correctly..